# Replace character in excel cell

Tags: c#, excel-formula

I'm exporting some data in sql table to a excel file using c# code. After exporting the data to the excel I need to append single quote any invalid text in the column A. (like staring with =,+)

I've added excel formula to remove the characters

added excel formula as

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)=\"= \",LEFT(A2,1)=\"+ \"),\"'\"&A2,A2)
```

After applying I need to get the same text by appending single quote to the start if it contains any invalid character. ('=xxx or '+yyy)
but cell contents changing to the 0 when formula applied

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated my understanding of the problem in a dummy Excel spreadsheet (screen shot below).

#### Dummy Excel spreadsheet:

- Cells `A1`, `A4`, and `A7` are data samples.  `A1` is good data that should not be altered.  `A4` and `A7` start with `=` and `+` respectively and should therefore be altered according to your requirements.
- Cells in Column `B` have different formulas in them operating on the data sample cells.  The exact formula used is displayed in its neighboring cell in Column `C` (i.e. `B1`'s formula is displayed in `C1`, `B2`'s formula is displayed in `C2`, etc.).

[image: Excel spreadsheet with test data and formulas]

#### Observations:

1. The formula resulting in `0` might be the result of the formula being applied to an incorrect cell.  In the example above, `B3`, `B6`, and `B9` all display `0`.  Note how the formulas are pointing to empty cells `A3`, `A6`, and `A9`.  If you are seeing `0`'s unexpectedly, double check that your formula is referencing the correct cells.
2. You listed an example of the formula as `=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)=\"= \",LEFT(A2,1)=\"+ \"),\"'\"&A2,A2)` which is presumably taken from a C# String given the `\"` escape characters?  In any case, there is an extra space after the `=` sign in `\"= \"` and after the `+` sign in `\"+ \"`.  The extra space will always cause the equalities to fail since the `LEFT(...,1)` functions are only returning 1 character.  At a minimum, try altering your formula to remove those extra spaces as follows:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)=\"=\",LEFT(A2,1)=\"+\"),\"'\"&A2,A2)
```

3. If none of these solutions are helpful, would you mind sharing a snippet of your Excel file with the formulas displayed in text as I did above?  That might help us diagnose the issue more easily.